# scipy convert coo string directly to numpy matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I already have a string in coo matrix format(row, col, value):

```
0 0 -1627.761282
0 1 342.811259
0 2 342.811259
0 3 171.372276
0 4 342.744553
0 5 342.744553
```

Now I want to convert my string directly to numpy matrix. Currently I have to write my string to file, then create a numpy matrix from file:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import numpy as np
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(matrix_str)
text = np.loadtxt( 'Output.txt', delimiter=' ' , dtype=str)
rows,cols,data = text.T
matrix = coo_matrix((data.astype(float), (rows.astype(int), cols.astype(int)))).todense()
```

How can I convert my string directly to numpy matrix without writing to file ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [StriongIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import io

with io.StringIO(matrix_str) as ss:
    rows, cols, data = np.loadtxt(ss).T
matrix = coo_matrix((data.astype(float), (rows.astype(int), cols.astype(int)))).todense()
```